# Access to a package views

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to use the views of my custom package without adding them to `view.php` conf file. I have created the following service provider and added it to `app.php` file.

```
class FooServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
      $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../views', 'foo');
    }
    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

I tried to use a package view by `view('foo.test')`. The view file is located in 'packages/foo/bar/views/test.blade.php'. However Laravel can not yet find the view file. Is there anything more I need to do? BTW, I do not need to publish view files to `resource/views` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have loaded the views in boot as you are doing right now:

```
class FooServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
      $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../views', 'foo');
    }
    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

Check your service provider loads from the appropriate folder as right now you are having `packages/foo/bar/views/teset.blade.php` so your service provider needs to be in `packages/foo/bar/providers` it can be `providers` or any `other folder name` just quoted for example and please make sure about the spell check, you are having blade file named `teset` and you are calling `test` then finally you can call this view in controller with something like this:

```
return ('foo::test')
```

**Update:**
Well as per the requirement you need to make changes in config on fly then this you need to have service provider something like this:

```
use Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder;
use Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider;

class WebViewServiceProvider  extends ViewServiceProvider
{

    /**
     *  Register View Folder
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function registerViewFinder()
    {

        $this->app->bind('view.finder', function ($app) {
            $paths = 'your view directory';

            return new FileViewFinder($app['files'], array(base_path($paths)));
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `teset` was a type in question. The question is how can I add my package folder to view folders. In the same way that is works in `config/view.php` without view namespace (`::`)